# Input and Output help in topological sorting

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, topological-sort

```
public class Problem3 {

    public static void main (String [] args){

        Scanner sc= new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter no. of Islands");
        int n= sc.nextInt();
         Graph g = new Graph (n);
        System.out.println("Enter no. of one-way bridges");
        int m= sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter no. of island you want to be intially on");
        int r= sc.nextInt();
       try{ for (int i=0; i<m;i++){ 
            System.out.println("This one-way bridge connects between");
            int u = sc.nextInt();
            int v = sc.nextInt();
            if(u == v || u>n || v>n){ throw new Bounds("");}
            else{ g.addEgde(u-1, v-1);}

        }
                g.topoSort();}
        catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid input!");
        }
       catch(Bounds e){
       System.out.println("Please enter a valid input!");
       }


    }
    public static class Bounds extends Exception{

    public Bounds (String message){
        super(message);
    }}



    static class Graph {
        int V;
        LinkedList<Integer>[] adjList;

        Graph(int V) {
            this.V = V;
            adjList = new LinkedList[V];
            for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) {
                adjList[i] = new LinkedList<>();
            }
        }

        public void addEgde(int u, int v) {
            adjList[u].addFirst(v);
        }

        public void topoSort() {
            boolean[] visited = new boolean[V];
            stack stack = new stack();
            for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) {
                if (!visited[i]) {
                    topoSortRE(i, visited, stack);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Topological Sort: ");
            int size = stack.size();
            for (int i = 0; i <size ; i++) {
                System.out.print(stack.pop()+ 1 + " ");
            }
        }

        public void topoSortRE(int s, boolean[] visited, stack stack) {
            visited[s] = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < adjList[s].size(); i++) {
                int vertex = adjList[s].get(i);
                if (!visited[vertex])
                    topoSortRE(vertex, visited, stack);
            }
            stack.push(s);
        }}}
```

The following code is an attempt to solve the following problem:
There are many islands that are connected by one-way bridges, that is, if a bridge connects
islands `a` and `b`, then you can only use the bridge to go from `a` to `b` but you cannot travel back
by using the same. If you are on island a, then you select (uniformly and randomly) one of
the islands that are directly reachable from a through the one-way bridge and move to that
island. You are stuck on an island if you cannot move any further. It is guaranteed that if
there is a directed path from one island to the second there is no path that leads from the
second back to the first. In other words the formed graph is a `Directed Acyclic Graph`.
Find the island that you are most likely to get stuck on; that is the island that you can
possibly reach with the maximum number of paths from all other islands.

Input format:
First line: Three integers `n` (the number of islands), `m` (the number of one-way bridges), and `r`
(the index of the island you are initially on)
Next m lines: Two integers `ui` and `vi` representing a one-way bridge from island `ui` to `vi`.
Output format:
Print the index of the island that you are most likely to get stuck on. If there are multiple
islands, then print them in the increasing order of indices (space separated values in a single
line).
Sample input

```
5, 7, 1
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
(1, 5)
(2, 4)
(2, 5)
(3, 4)
```

Sample output

```
4
```

I wrote the code to topologically sort the graph but I am having issues with how to make the input r the intial island and also how to make the output be the most probable island to be stuck on. I know that the island I'm most likely to be stuck on is the island that has the most indegrees and no outdegrees but don't know how to implement that.

Comment: Not an answer, so posting as a comment instead: I'm not really sure how the topological sort is going to help solving this problem. It is also not true that the node with the highest indegree is your answer (counter example: `(1, 2), (2, 4), (1, 3), (3, 4), (1, 5),  (5, 8), (1, 6), (6, 8), (1, 7), (7, 8), (8, 9)`: 4 has indegree 2 but there are only 2 paths to 4, whereas there are 3 paths to 9, which has indegree 1). I would maybe try to look at it as a max flow problem, although I'm not sure that will work either.

Answer (score 0):

For each node make a value (real number) representing probability that you will reach it from your starting island. At first, set this value for initial node to 1 and 0 for other nodes.

During the topological sort, when you're in node v, add its probability value divided by number of neighbors to each neighbor's value (in other words, since you know that the probability of getting to v is v.value, then the probability of reaching its neighbor should be increased by v.value * ppb of choosing this neighbor, that is 1 / #_of_neighbors). In this way, whenever you're in some node during topological sort, its value will be equal to the total probability of reaching it.

Your answer is an ending island (node with outdegree 0) with largest value.

Your topological sort seems wrong, you're doing something that looks like DFS. In topological sort you want to visit each vertex after visiting all vertices with an edge ending in it.

About implementation, I changed your DFS into topological sort and added those probabilities I've talked about. I left the part about choosing best ending vertex to you, I don't think doing all the work for someone is educational in any way. Also, I do not guarantee that my changes below do not contain any spelling mistakes, etc. I did my best, but I have not run this code.

```
static class Graph {
    int V;
    LinkedList<Integer>[] adjList;

    Graph(int V) {
        this.V = V;
        adjList = new LinkedList[V];
        probability = new double[V];
        for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) {
            adjList[i] = new LinkedList<>();
        }
    }

    public void addEgde(int u, int v) {
        adjList[u].addFirst(v);
    }

    public void topoSort(int start) {
        double[] probability;
        probability[start] = 1;
        int[] indegree = new int[V];
        stack stack = new stack();

        for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) {
            probability[i] = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < adjList[i].size(); ++j) {
                 indegree[adjList[i][j]] += 1;
            }
        }

        probability[start] = 1;

        for(int i = 0; i < V; ++i)
        {
            if(indegree[i] == 0)
              stack.push(i);
        }

        while(stack.size())
        {
           int v = stack.pop();
           for (int i = 0; i < adjList[v].size(); ++i)
           {
                indegree[adjList[v][i]] -= 1;
                probability[adjList[v][i]] += probability[v] / (double)(adjList[v].size());
                if(indegree[adjList[v][i]] == 0)
                  stack.push(adjList[v][i]);
           }
        }

         //probability array now contains all probabilities to visit each node

        }
    }
}
```